# MYSQL - prepare stmt and execute stmt and adding WHERE and LIKE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to build the next stored proc but it's not working.

```
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (`a` like `%?%` OR `b` like `%?%` OR `c` like `%?%` OR `d` like `%?%` OR `e` like `%?%`) LIMIT ?, ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @search, @skip, @rows;
```

Basically, I'm trying to search for a string inside one of the columns and return the rows with the columns who fits.
Please help me fix it since I'm getting the next error:

```
Unknown column '%?%' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: number of variables should be equivalent to number of question mark...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the number of ? should be equal to number of parameters after `USING` clause. also you have given wrong quotes ? instead of `"?"` try:

```
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (`a` like "%?%" OR `b` like "%?%" OR `c` like "%?%" OR `d` like "%?%" OR `e` like "%?%") LIMIT ?, ?';

EXECUTE STMT USING @search, @search, @search, @search, @search, @skip, @rows;
```

or try

```
SET @query1 = CONCAT('
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a, b, c, d, e
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE (`a` like "%',@search,'%" OR
        `b` like "%',@search,'%" OR
        `c` like "%',@search,'%" OR
        `d` like "%',@search,'%" OR
        `e` like "%',@search,'%")
    LIMIT ',@skip,', ',@rows,'');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; 
    EXECUTE stmt; 
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total_rows;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: After the change, I'm getting the error "Incorrect arguments to EXECUTE"

Comment: can I count the rows in the same execution ? or how do I call it again with just counting the rows?

Comment: EDIT: Added SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS after select and after execution of query get total records with MySQL function FOUND_ROWS()

Answer (score 0):

The given example on mysql seems to show that the count of question marks
should be similar the the count of parameters?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Am I wrong?

In your case this means seven question marks and also seven parameters.

all the best

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT a, b, c, d, e FROM TABLE_1 WHERE (`a` like "%?%" OR `b` like "%?%" OR `c` like "%?%" OR `d` like "%?%" OR `e` like "%?%") LIMIT ?, ?';

EXECUTE STMT USING @search, @search, @search, @search, @search, @skip, @rows;
```

**NOTE**

Number of variables should be equals to number of question mark that we have.

You had 7 question mark and only 3 variables. So error comes for 4th `?`.